# Running a Heavy Scheduled MongoDB Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**PROBLEM**: I have a list of projects that have expiration times that I have to check for with a scheduler. If the project is expired, I must mark it in the database.

I have over 2k of project lists that are becoming heavy to run a scheduler on (With my current logic). I am using `node-schedule` as well. I have it set to 45 minutes (which isn't ideal and now it's starting to drag)

**Question**: How can I optimize this scheduled job? Because I would like the expirations to happen somewhat real-time if possible. I am using `projects[x].activities[y].status.expired` and `projects[x].activities[y].status.startTime`

**Schema**

```
const StudentSchema= new Schema({
...
 projects: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Title is required for Project"]
      },

      activities: [
        {
          name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          gradingMechanism: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["Peer to Peer", "Mentor", "Instructor"]
          },
          totalPointsPossible: { type: Number },
          status: {
            text: {
              type: String,
              enum: [
                "Not Started",
                "Started",
                "Awaiting Grade",
                "Passing",
                "Failing"
              ],
              default: "Not Started"
            },
            graded: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            grade: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            pass: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            expired: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            lastSave: { type: Date },
            hasStarted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            startTime: { type: Date },
            completionTime: { type: Date }
          }
            }
          ],


        }
      ],
...
```

**CODE**

```
  // Expire Activities in Projects
  schedule.scheduleJob("*/45 * * * *", async function () {
    const profile = await StudentProfile.find({});

    StudentProfile.find(
      { "projects.activities.status.expired": { $eq: false } },
      "projects"
    )
      .then((profiles) => {
        let promiseList = [];
        profiles.map((profile) => {
          const { projects } = profile;
          let saveProfile = false;

          projects.map((project, projKey) => {
            project.activities.map((activity, actKey) => {
              if (
                typeof activity.status.startTime !== "undefined" &&
                !activity.status.expired
              ) {
                var startTime = new Date(activity.status.startTime);
                var activityTimeout = 72;
                // If startTime+<X TIME> is less than or equal to current time,
                // Mark activity as expired
                if (
                  startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() + activityTimeout) <=
                  new Date()
                ) {
                  profile.projects[projKey].activities[
                    actKey
                  ].status.expired = true;
                  profile.projects[projKey].activities[actKey].status.text =
                    "Awaiting Grade";
                  saveProfile = true;
                }
              }
            });
          });
          if (saveProfile) {
            promiseList.push(profile.save());
          }
        });

        Promise.all(promiseList)
          .then((profiles) => {
            if (profiles.length > 0) {
              console.log("Marked " + profiles.length + " profile's projects");
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your implementation is using multiple nested loops to evaluate the returned data in a way to achieve your requirements.

This could be simplified, using the database to achieve part of this requirement. Using a $where statement and the `startTime` with a calculated expiry date, it's a simple condition, eliminating most of the required looping.

Instead of returning a list of all non-expired records, you return a list of all records that meet your expiration criteria. (in theory this should be less than the amount of non-expired records).

To achieve the other part of your requirement, you'd then perform the final operations (updating) as you know these records have expired (as they meet your conditions).

This *should* go a long way to improving the performance of that scheduled job, you're no longer evaluating the return in your code, only performing the update operations (something you can't really avoid).

The main issue here is complexity, you're looping multiple times over arrays to evaluate different conditions, each additional project will increase the processing time and memory usage.

TL;DR: the MongoDB part doesn't have to be heavy, lighten it using some method (even not from above), find a less complex way of processing the workload.

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-gt
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-pre

With regard to the `.pre` option, I would even consider up-front scheduling of the job with the expired time, again as a way of simplifying your logic.

I personally use Bull, Bull includes a mechanism for delayed/scheduled jobs, then it's almost the real-time solution you seek. You'd need to find the equivalent method within node-schedule.

The benefit of the scheduled approach, is you only ever process one at a time, it'll never slow down. If you use a job queue, then each job is processed when a worker is available, reducing workload of the processes. This does increase the infrastructure complexity, but usually at an increase of overall performance.

This is just a suggestion, it's worth looking into in my mind.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use `$where` in a deeply nested array? I'm not sure how I can implement that here.

Comment: To avoid needing the startTime property, I would recommend using Mongoose and a hook to calculate the expireTime, eliminating any additional calculation, then you'd use a similar query to `$eq: false`, instead using `expireTime: { $gt: new Date() }`. However, I believe $where does work (although that was just an example), you can use the operators to your advantage was the point behind the example, reducing the complexity in your app code. I've updated my answer with some reference maybe a better alternative.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. I've never used this part of mongoose!

Comment: I *think* it'd be the simplest solution, if not then may consider the other solutions above, however I feel that would eliminate a lot of the additional complexity everywhere else, as you already have the value you need. Again, requiring the query only to return the expired documents. Good luck though!